# Errors while opening dicom files in R

Tags: r, dicom

I am trying to open dicom files in R using following code:

```
library(oro.dicom)
dcmobject <- readDICOMFile(filename)
```

Some files open properly and I can display them. However, some files give errors of different types:

First error: For some, I get the error:

```
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

Second error: In others, I get following error with dicom file:  http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/OT-MONO2-8-hip.gz  :

```
Error in readDICOMFile(filename) : DICM != DICM
```

Third error: This file gives following error: http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/CT-MONO2-16-chest.gz

```
Error in parsePixelData(fraw[(132 + dcm$data.seek + 1):fsize], hdr, endian,  : 
  Number of bytes in PixelData not specified
```

Fourth error: One dicom file gives following error:

```
Error in rawToChar(fraw[129:132]) : embedded nul in string: '\0\0\b'
```

How can I get rid of these errors and display these images in R?

EDIT:

This sample file gives the error 'embed nul in string...':
http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/CT-MONO2-12-lomb-an2.gz

```
> jj = readDICOMFile( "CT-MONO2-12-lomb-an2.dcm" )
Error in rawToChar(fraw[129:132]) : embedded nul in string: '3\0\020'
```

Comment: I have downloaded the two gzipped files (DICOM I assume) and will most likely take a look at them during the weekend.

Comment: Good to hear from developer of oro.dicom. It is a great package, but there may be some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four different errors highlighted in this ticket:

1. `Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection`

This is not a problem with **oro.dicom**, it is simply the fact that the file path and/or name has been mis-specified.

2. `Error in readDICOMFile(filename) : DICM != DICM`

The file is not a valid DICOM file.  That is, section 7.1 in Part 10 of the DICOM Standard (available at http://dicom.nema.org) specifies that there should be (a) the File Preample of length 128 bytes and (b) the four-byte DICOM Prefix "DICM" at the beginning of a DICOM file.  The file OT-MONO2-8-hip does not follow this standard.  One can investigate this problem further using the `debug=TRUE` input parameter

```r
> dcm <- readDICOMFile("OT-MONO2-8-hip.dcm", debug=TRUE)
# First 128 bytes of DICOM header =
  [1] 08 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 b0 00 00 00 08 00 08 00 2e 00 00 00 4f 52 49 47 49 4e 41 4c 5c 53 45
 [32] 43 4f 4e 44 41 52 59 5c 4f 54 48 45 52 5c 41 52 43 5c 44 49 43 4f 4d 5c 56 41 4c 49 44 41 54
 [63] 49 4f 4e 20 08 00 16 00 1a 00 00 00 31 2e 32 2e 38 34 30 2e 31 30 30 30 38 2e 35 2e 31 2e 34
 [94] 2e 31 2e 31 2e 37 00 08 00 18 00 1a 00 00 00 31 2e 33 2e 34 36 2e 36 37 30 35 38 39 2e 31 37
[125] 2e 31 2e 37
Error in readDICOMFile("OT-MONO2-8-hip.dcm", debug = TRUE) : DICM != DICM
```

It is apparent that the first 128 bytes contain information.  One can now use the parameters `skipFirst128=FALSE` and `DICM=FALSE` to start reading information from the beginning of the file

```r
dcm <- readDICOMFile("OT-MONO2-8-hip.dcm", skipFirst128=FALSE, DICM=FALSE)
image(t(dcm$img), col=grey(0:64/64), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image: OT-MONO2-8-hip]

  3.

```r
Error in parsePixelData(fraw[(132 + dcm$data.seek + 1):fsize], hdr, endian,  : 
  Number of bytes in PixelData not specified
```

The file CT-MONO2-16-chest.dcm is encoded using JPEG compression.  The R package **oro.dicom** does not support compression.

4. `Error in rawToChar(fraw[129:132]) : embedded nul in string: '\0\0\b'`

I have to speculate, since the file is not available for direct interrogation.  This problem is related to the check for "DICM" characters as part of the DICOM standard.  If it failed, then one can assume the file is not a valid DICM file.  I will look into making this error more informative in future versions of **oro.dicom**.

EDIT:  Thank-you for providing a link to the appropriate file.  The file is in "ARC-NEMA 2" format.  The R package **oro.dicom** has not been designed to read such a file.  I have modified the code to improve the error tracking.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying most issues. The link of sample dicom file that gives the error 'embedded nul in string..' has been added to the EDIT in question above.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a response to this specific file.  Please note that the file is not a valid DICOM file.

Comment: Thanks for addressing all problems.

Comment: @ bjwhitcher: please see this post also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819617/what-could-be-the-reason-for-bad-dicom-image-plot