# What could be the reason for bad dicom image plot

Tags: r, rgb, dicom

What could be the reason that the dicom file of this usual x-ray is getting plotted in a messed up manner:

[image]

The algorithm used is as follows:

The original image matrix is 3d:

```
int [1:2014, 1:2014, 1:3] 110 51 99 113 52 101 111 53 102 110 ...
```

This rgb is converted to gray scale by formula:

```
gray = 0.3*mat[,,1] + 0.59*mat[,,2] + 0.11*mat[,,3] ;
```

And then it is plotted after specifying colors as:

```
grey(0:64/64)
```

Where could be the error?

I am using oro.dicom package in R with function:

```
jj = readDICOMFile(fname, endian = "little", flipud = TRUE, DICM = TRUE, skipSequence = FALSE, pixelData = TRUE, warn = -1, debug = FALSE)
```

and it returns a the matrix jj$img whose structure is:

```
int [1:2014, 1:2014, 1:3] 110 51....
```

I then convert it to gray and plot it. If it was rgba, the matrix would have been 2014*2014*4 rather than *3. The header of dicom image mentions "PhotometricInterpretation" as "RGB". The header also mentions rows and columns as 2014 each. Could it be related to bit problem: leadtools.com/sdk/medical/dicom-spec17.htm

Edit: Bits allocated is 8, bits stored is 8 and highBit is 7.

Following is the link of sample dicom image which has similar image matrix and give similar error: http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/US-RGB-8-esopecho.gz

Comment: Looks like a stride issue to me.  Like you're indexing assuming RGB and it's RGBA or something along those lines.

Comment: Bits allocated is 8, bits stored is 8 and highBit is 7. Does that help?

Comment: How do I convert rgba to gray scale? I could not immediately find it on the net.

Comment: Well your alpha channel is probably irrelevant.  Just add up the RGB the same way you're doing (0.3r + 0.59g + 0.11b) and ignore the alpha.  If that's even the problem.  It could be lot of things, but  the indexing being wrong is what the looks like.  I don't really know what your input format is.  How did you make that 2048x2048x3 array?

Comment: I am using oro.dicom package in R with function: jj = readDICOMFile(fname, endian = "little", flipud = TRUE, DICM = TRUE, skipSequence = FALSE, pixelData = TRUE, warn = -1, debug = FALSE) and it returns a the matrix jj$img whose structure is: int [1:2014, 1:2014, 1:3] 110 51.... I then convert it to gray and plot it. If it was rgba, the matrix would have been 2014*2014*4 rather than *3. The header of dicom image mentions "PhotometricInterpretation" as "RGB". The header also mentions rows and columns as 2014 each. Could it be related to bit problem: leadtools.com/sdk/medical/dicom-spec17.htm

Comment: Is there anyway you can share the file?

Comment: Following image has similar matrix and is also not displayed properly: http://www.barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/files/US-RGB-8-esopecho.gz

Comment: Please see the corrected link in comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readDICOMFile` might have a bug. You can fix by rearrange the image array:

```
jj = readDICOMFile(fname, flipud = FALSE, DICM = TRUE, skipSequence = FALSE, pixelData = TRUE, warn = -1, debug = FALSE)
img <- jj$img # extract image part
img <- aperm(array(c(aperm(img, c(2, 1, 3))), c(3, 256, 120)), c(3, 2, 1)) # rearrange dimension
img <- img[120:1,,] # flip ud
grid::grid.raster(scales::rescale(img))
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

`readDICOMFile` has another bug. This is what you want.
You may be better to report this but to the authors of `oro.dicom`.

```
img <- jj$img # extract image part
img <- aperm(array(c(aperm(img, c(2, 1, 3))), c(3, 256, 120)), c(3, 2, 1)) # rearrange dimension

# conversion b/w unsigned and signed
img <- ifelse(img > 0, img, 256+img)

# window-ing
wc <- 127
ww <- 255

ymin <- 0
ymax <- 1

img2 <- ifelse(img <= wc - 0.5 - (ww-1)/2, ymin, 
               ifelse(img > wc - 0.5 + (ww-1)/2, ymax,
                      ((img - (wc - 0.5)) / (ww - 1) + 0.5) * (ymax - ymin) + ymin
                      ))

grid::grid.raster(img2)
```

[image]

Comment: It will helpful if you could also explain what your code is doing.

Comment: Yes, it works. However, the image looks very different from original one probably due to window width/center/colorpalette difference. How can we adjust these so that it looks like original (which I am posting in my question above).

Comment: The window center and width of this image are 127 and 256, respectively. (and it does not need to be flipped upside down)

Comment: Great. You have created the code to display these images properly. I will just wait for some more time for any other answers before accepting yours. It will be even better if you could explain in some detail.

Comment: Just a clarification: "conversion b/w unsigned and signed" is needed for all dicom images or does one need to check header of each image?

Comment: If DICOM data is unsigned, you need the conversion (and I think 8-bit DICOM is usually or absolutely unsigned). But this conversion works only with 8 bit data. Different conversion is required for 16 bit data.

Comment: This image had Bits allocated is 8, bits stored is 8 and highBit is 7. Another dicom file has Bits allocated is 16, bits stored is 12 and highBit is 11. That file opens well but is MONOCHROME2 and not rgb.